# How do i make my game not speed up/slow down depending on the fps in java?

Tags: java, time, frame-rate

So when I'm running a game I'm working on, the FPS will go up and down. But then so will the in game time. more fps, faster movement. less fps, slower movement. I'm using the javax.swing.Timer class with a 10ms delay and a personalized ActionListener class. Does anyone know how to get rid of these time conundrums? Something like Unity's Time.deltaTime would be perfect, as that's what I'm used to.

Comment: Decouple the idea of "game time" from the "fps", this means that you're tracking "ticks" or "cycles" on each iteration which determines how things in the game change, rather than been tied to the frequency of updates. In animation, this is commonly known as "time based" rather than "delta based".   This does make it a little more complicated, as you need to record the start "tick" of an event and on each interaction, determine the amount of time which has passed

Comment: FPS should determine the frequency of drawing only.  It sounds like you are putting your game logic in the ActionListener along with your drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record the time in your `ActionListener` class:

```java
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private long previousStartTime = -1;
    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = previousStartTime != -1 ? now - previousStartTime : 0;
        previousStartTime = now;
        
        // use elapsedTime
        // e.g.
        double pixelsToMove = speedPerMs * elapsedTime;
    }
}
```

On the first iteration the `elapsedTime` will be zero.

Comment: what will this tell me other than how long it takes between frames/ticks?

Comment: It tells you how many milliseconds elapsed since the last update, so that you can scale movement. But perhaps I've misunderstood the issue?

Comment: ah, so would i be able to just multiply it to a bunch of stuff and make it work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but I was aiming to make `elapsedTime` the same as what I imagined `deltaTime` would be.

Comment: yep, it looks like it worked, or at peast well enough, thanks!